# multiline regex match string replacement on large file

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I have a large mysqldump (4+ gigs), and we have an archive type table which [suffers from this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37182) Net result is that I need to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT counter to zero.  Did manage to do the replacement, but it was ugly, involving splitting the file into smaller chunks, then grepping to find the table, looking to see the number I wanted to change and then using `sed` on the original file to replace just that match on the auto increment.  Like I said, horrible, but it worked.

So - I have tried to decipher multiline sed and didn't get that far.  What I want to do is to seek to the table name I'm interested in, and then from that point find the next `AUTO_INCREMENT=` , and then match the number in it, and make it zero.  Here's the table:  (assume there is scads of data before this point, and after it)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `archive_exported_problems`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `archive_exported_problems` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `export_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `problem_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE AUTO_INCREMENT=478 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I want to do, is to (automatically) scan the file until it matches

```
(?:CREATE TABLE `archive_exported_problems).*?AUTO_INCREMENT=(\d+)
```

(regex which seems to work) and then replace the capture group with 0

I assume this is possible - any help most appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that  the `CREATE TABLE` phrase and the `AUTO_INCREMENT=` phrase could occur on the _same_ line?  Or, will they always be on different lines as in your example?

Comment: It's a mysqldump, so, I would assume that they will always be on different lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `perl` is an option then it is easier using `DOTALL` flag in `perl` like this:

```
perl -00 -pe 
 's/(?s)(CREATE TABLE `archive_exported_problems`.*?AUTO_INCREMENT)=\d+/$1=0/' file.sql

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `archive_exported_problems`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `archive_exported_problems` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `export_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `problem_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Options used are:

```
-00    # slurps whole file
(?s)   # enable DOTALL flag for regex
```

Comment: Just to clarify "-00 # slurps whole file" - that's definitely not what I want to do as it's a huge file.  [This link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) suggests -00 does it in "paragraph" mode? Does that mean it breaks on two line breaks or similar?

Comment: Yes I believe -00 will break it by paragraphs. There is a -0 also that you can use instead of -00. Sorry I am on mobile and traveling so unable to test these options.

Comment: I dug up `-00` a bit further. I believe `-00` will serve you good as it slurps in paragraph mode. A paragraph is text between two newlines. All the other newlines get ignored.

Comment: Yip, am just double checking against the db that is on prod at the moment - but locally against a very similar copy it worked perfectly.. so thanks very much indeed.  Interestingly, I had t redirect the output to a file, else I was finding everything printed to the screen.  Anyway, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
$ sed -r '/CREATE TABLE `archive_exported_problems`/,/AUTO_INCREMENT=/ {s/(AUTO_INCREMENT)=[[:digit:]]+/\1=0/;}' file
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `archive_exported_problems`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `archive_exported_problems` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `export_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `problem_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For Mac OSX (BSD), try:

```
$ sed -E -e '/CREATE TABLE `archive_exported_problems`/,/AUTO_INCREMENT=/ {s/(AUTO_INCREMENT)=[[:digit:]]+/\1=0/;}' file
```

#### How it works

- `/CREATE TABLE`archive_exported_problems`/, /AUTO_INCREMENT=/`

  This restricts the subsequent commands to ranges on lines that start with a line containing `CREATE TABLE 'archive_exported_problems'` and end with a line containing `AUTO_INCREMENT=`.
- `s/(AUTO_INCREMENT)=[[:digit:]]+/\1=0/`

  This performs the substitution that you wanted.

#### Limitation

This approach assumes that the `CREATE TABLE` phrase and the `AUTO_INCREMENT=` phrase will never be on the same line.  If that is not true, we need to make some minor changes.

Comment: It probably will be run (in production) on ubuntu, however, running on my mac with the command above I get: `sed: 1: "/CREATE TABLE `archive_ ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: @patrick-davey (a) My tests were done on GNU sed so it should work the same on Ubuntu.  (b) If I recall correctly, OSX/BSD sed likes a semicolon before the brace.  Please try the code in the updated answer.